# Installing SSL Certificates for a Processor Gateway

Tags: php, linux, apache, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have experience installing SSL Certificate for sites that I am hosting, but I am unfamiliar with configuring a server to have the needed certificates for outgoing connections.

We're preparing to process payments through the Cielo gateway. They provide [a list of certificates with downloads](https://developercielo.github.io/en/manual/cielo-ecommerce#how-to-install-the-extended-validation-certificate-on-the-store-server?). The documentation states:

> Just install the following three files in the server Trustedstore. Cielo does not offer support to the installation of the Certificate. If you are unsure about how to install the EV Certificate, then you should contact your server vendor support.

I don't know where to put the files or even if I really need them. I found [this page which talks about checking a CA Chain installation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9605/69/how-to-check-ca-chain-installation), but I'm not sure how to read the output of this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect api.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br:443
```

One of the final lines in the output says this, so I am likely missing something:

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I tried placing the certificate files exactly as named from Cielo in `/etc/ssl/certs/`, but I get the same output from `openssl`.

Comment: Did you put the CA's certificate in the /etc/ssl/certs directory? It looks to me like it does not have the CA cert that signed the server certificate

Comment: I placed the four supplied certificates in that directory. I retained the file names.

Comment: Did you run the command to import them? update-ca-trust for AWS Linux

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins - No. I will look into that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My server is using AWS Linux. Based on [the manual for `update-ca-trust`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-update-ca-trust/), I placed the provided certificates in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` with this renaming:

- `Root.crt` > `cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br-root.crt`
- `Intermediate1.crt` > `cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br-intermediate1.crt`
- `Intermediate2.crt` > `cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br-intermediate2.crt`
- `ServerCertificate.crt` > `cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br-server-certificate.crt`

I then ran the following commands:

- `yum install ca-certificates`
  *Made sure the package was up-to-date*
- `update-ca-trust extract`
  *Built the certs - output the message: `update-ca-trust: Warning: The dynamic CA configuration feature is in the disabled state`*
- `update-ca-trust enable`
  *Addressed warning from above*
- `openssl s_client -connect api.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br:443`
  *Confirmed that connections now work*
- `service httpd reload`
  *PHP code running on Apache now has the new certs*